# Corebluetooth to get the temperature

Tags: ios5, ios6, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Form core bluetooth frame work how can I get the body temperature or heart rate using iPhone?

Comment: What device are you trying to interact with, and can you please post the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the device.

Apple has a nice example for the wahoo BlurHR heart rate monitor on their [web site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Listings/HeartRateMonitor_HeartRateMonitorAppDelegate_m.html). The same ideas can be used to access any Bluetooth LE device.

You can also find a sample app that accesses the accelerometer, push buttons, battery level indicator and proximity alert written in techBASIC [here](http://www.byteworks.us/Byte_Works/Blog/Entries/2012/8/20_Controlling_Bluetooth_LE_Devices_with_techBASIC.html). It has the advantage of accessing BLE devices entirely from the iPhone or iPad, without writing code in objective C on the Mac. This may be better or worse, depending on your situation. The article steps through how to connect to BLE devices. THe ideas will work for any BLE device, and apply equally well to iOS.